# Outer function argument not displayed when debugging inner function in chrome

Tags: javascript, debugging, closures, google-chrome-devtools

I have function like:

```
const outer = payload => dispatch => {
   debugger;
return 0;
}
```

[image: chrome devtools screenshot]

Should I see `payload` variable when debugging it in chrome devtools? I was looking for it in closures as you can see in the screenshot. There is no `payload` there or I cannot find it. However when I change the code to:

```
const outer = payload => dispatch => {
   console.log({ payload });
   debugger;
return 0;
}
```

I can see `payload` variable appearing under one of the closure boxes on the right side when debugging.

I think I don't fully understand the behaviour of closures(?) Could you please tell me in short how these two codes work behind the scenes?

Comment: It's because V8 removes variables that aren't referenced anymore in the scope. You can switch to a parent frame in the call stack to see its scope.

Comment: ok I did what @wOxxOm suggested. I switch the `call stack`(in call stack box in chrone devtools) in my case to `_callee3$ (index.js:242)` I could then enrol `local` scope and I could see the `payload`. Thanks!